# PHP pagination buttons

Tags: php, html, pagination

I'm trying to add forward and back buttons for my table data in my php html pagination page. So far i've added the base codes for the pagination to work itself

```
<?php
    $sql_event="select * from event ";
    $event_list=mysqli_query($con,$sql_event);

    $whole_amount = mysqli_num_rows($event_list);

    $results_amount = 3;

    $number_of_pages = ceil($whole_amount / $results_amount) ;



    if(!isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }


    $resulting_parts = ($page-1)*$results_amount;

    $sql_event = 'select * from event LIMIT ' . $resulting_parts . ',' . $results_amount;
    $event_list =mysqli_query($con,$sql_event);

?>
```

:
:
:

```
<div id ="scrollarea">
        <?php


   for($page=1; $page <= $number_of_pages ; $page++)
    {
        echo '<a href="admin_events_template.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a>';
    }


?>
</div>
```

Focusing on the php coding, is there a way to add 'previous' and 'forward' for the pagination links ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to using "GET" to access at the number of page, add or withdraw one, according on the button.

You need to put on a if you get to the max or min.

```
$CurrentPage = $_GET['page'];
echo '<a href="admin_events_template.php?page=' . $CurrentPage-1 . '">' Previous. '</a>';   
echo '<a href="admin_events_template.php?page=' . $CurrentPage+1 . '">' forward'</a>';
```

You can add somthing like that :

```
echo '<a href="admin_events_template.php?page=' .  $CurrentPage = $CurrentPage > 0 ? $CurrentPage : 1. '">' Previous. '</a>';
```

Comment: `$CurrentPage-1` ... What if `$CurrentPage=0` ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need to create prev/next buttons.
First of all you need to get count of posts from database.
After create constant like posts per page and step constant.

Formula: pagenum * posts_per_page, 
if ((pagenum * posts_per_page) >= postscount) - disable next button
if ((pagenum * posts_per_page) <= 0) - disable prev button

========

About buttons - use get param and check if < 1 and if > total / postcount and post per page.

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id ="scrollarea">
<?php
$currentPage = @$_GET['page'];

$number_of_pages = 6;

$pagination = '';
// Show next
if ($currentPage > 1) {
    $nextPage = $currentPage;
    $pagination .= '<a href="admin_events_template.php?page=' . ++$nextPage . '">(Next)</a> ';
}

for ($page = 1; $page <= $number_of_pages ; $page++) {
    $pagination .= '<a href="admin_events_template.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
}
// Show last
if ($currentPage !== $number_of_pages && $number_of_pages > 1) {
    $pagination .= ' <a href="admin_events_template.php?page=' . $number_of_pages . '">(Last)</a>';
}

echo $pagination;
?>
</div>
```